# Exception while parsing a double value with jackson-csv

Tags: java, jackson, fasterxml

i have some problems with parsing double values from a CSV-File with fasterxml.
The CSV-File is beginning with the header `ID;Size;...` the line below is `1;27.98;...`
Also I have a model to map the CSV-File:

```
class Model{
   private String id;
   private double size;
   //...
}
```

Further I've configured the CSV-Parser following the instructions on the tutorial page:

```
//...
CsvSchema schema = CsvSchema.builder().addColumn("id").addColumn("size")
     .setColumnSeparator(';')
     .setEscapeChar('"')
     .build();
CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
MappingIterator<Model> it = mapper.reader(Model.class).with(schema)
    .readValues(new File(csvFile));
while(it.hasNext()){
    Model row = it.next();
    System.out.println(row);
}
```

When I run the parser the "id" is parsed properly but the compiler thows an exception with the message `RuntimeJsonMappingException: Can not construct an instance of double from String value 'size':not a valid Double value`.

I do not understand what exactly the problem is because the value 27.98 is a valid double value.

Am I missing something in the configuration?

Comment: can you please post a sample of your CSV file?

Comment: Looks like it's parsing the header of your csv file. The string 'size' is not a valid double.

Comment: I was thing about this too and tried it also with dleting the header. This is the CSV-File:<br/>id;size;rad;thickness <br/>01;27.98;1;1.5;

Comment: What is the exact error message you get if your csv has no header, such as '01;19.99;1;2'? (no need for a final ; at the end of line)

Comment: Omg. I was using the wrong CSV all the time. I deleted the header from the wrong one :D. Thanks for your help. It was the header of course. "size" is not a valid double value :D

Answer (score 1):

Use `.withHeader()` on your `CsvMapper` like such:

```
CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
CsvSchema schema = mapper.schemaFor(Model.class).withHeader();
```

You can then keep your header in your csv file.